# Get background color of element and set it as border-color of other element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the actual color of the primary btn of bootstrap and set it as a border volor of another element (it should be flexible, so it does not matter which bootstrap theme you use).

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
var primarycolor = $(".primary").css("background-color");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after").css("border-left", "10px solid " + primarycolor + "!important");
});
```

But it does not work.
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Post your markup also.

Comment: Not with the information posted. But move the first line into `domReady()` as well and see if that helps…

Comment: Put your primarycolor assignment inside your ready function.

Comment: why you put your first line outside the domready function? put it also inside.

Comment: You do  know you can't select the `:after` or `:before` pseudo elements with Js/JQ as they are not in the DOM....don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var primarycolor = $(".primary").css("background-color");//getting color after document loaded
    $(".btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after").css("border-left", "10px solid " + primarycolor + "!important");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo version satisfying your requirements.Do check

http://plnkr.co/edit/mFWCbeu8sgPpJVFqJe1h?p=preview